# How to correctly code SocketListen[] to produce appropriate response to HTTP POST "Header" and "Body" from URLRead[]

Tags: networking

Mathematica has great *HTTP* capabilities, including *POST*, *GET*, *PUT*, but the devil in the detail is poorly documented, which results in unexpected behavour when using, for example, `SocketListen` and `URLRead` to process *HTTP POST*.

So as a starting point, let's take (1) `SocketListen` example under (2) "Applications":

(1) https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SocketListen.html

(2) direct link to "Applications": https://wolfram.com/xid/0yvwe3jh7dmw-d9zqvp

Now here in the example we have:

```
response = URLRead[url]
```

Let's convert it to:

```
response = URLRead[HTTPRequest[url, <|"Body" -> StringRepeat["a", 1025]|>]]
```

Once we run "Evaluate Notebook", we get the following error message:
*ZeroMQLink`Private`ZMQWriteInternal::Socket operation failed: Host unreachable*

What just happenned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Relevant fact:**
"8.2.3 Use of the 100 (Continue) Status"
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html

`URLRead` sends POST in two parts: 1) *Headers* and 2) *Body*. *Body* can be communicated in fragments - see **"POST Body fragments"** at the bottom.

The `SocketListen` example in "Applications" is triggered first time for *Headers* and second time for *Body*.

However, when it is triggered with *Headers*, it invokes:

```
Close[client]
```

thus when it is triggered the second time for *Body*, the socket is already closed for communications via `WriteString`, which causes the `ZeroMQLink` error.

Consequently, the code logic in `SocketListen` should be adjusted to process first *Headers* then *Body*.

How to do this? Analyze the contents received by `SocketListen` by adding

```
data=assoc["Data"]
```

and

```
If[StringContainsQ[data,"POST / HTTP/1.1"] == True,
 Print["Headers"];WriteString[client,"Headers Response"],
 Print["Body"];WriteString[client,"Body Response"];Close[client]
]
```

Below is a modified `SocketListen` code from the "Applications" example, which does nothing when it receives *Headers* and responds via `WriteString` when it *receives Body*:

```
listener = SocketListen[Automatic, Function[{assoc},​With[{client = assoc["SourceSocket"],

   ​(* Add data = assoc["Data"], below *)
   data = assoc["Data"],
   ​html = "<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello from the Wolfram Language</h1>
Today's date is :  " <> DateString[] <> "
</body>
</html>"},

   (* Add Print[data] below to visualize HTTP POST parts *)
   Print[data]; 

   (* Introduce condition to WriteString[], Close[] to separate between Headers and Body and avoid "ZeroMQLink`Private`ZMQWriteInternal::Socket operation failed: Host unreachable" *)
(* Passing: 100-continue upon receiving Headers is not required and in fact triggers HTTP 0.9 format error *)
   If[StringContainsQ[data,"POST / HTTP/1.1"] == False, ​WriteString[client, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: " <> DateString[] <> " " <> $TimeZoneEntity["ShortName"] <> "
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: " <> ToString[StringLength[html]] <> "\n\n" <> html <>
      ​"\n\n"
    ​];
   Close[client]]​]​]​]
```

Always great to have illustrative examples and save someone else research time and investigation effort!

**POST Body fragments**

To process fragments, obtain the *Content-Length* value from the *Header* then accumulate received *Body* data until its length equals *Content-Length*.

Comment: The is not an answer to the question. You should edit the question making clear what you changed.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100655)

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi updated for revisit